# cleanest way to glue generated Flask app code (Swagger-Codegen) to backend implementation

Tags: python, rest, flask, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have:

1. a library that does [Stuff]
2. a swagger API definition, which is roughly #1 with minor differences to map cleanly to a REST service
3. a flask app generated #2 using Swagger-Codegen - eg results in python controller functions roughly one-to-one with #1.

My intent is that the flask app (all generated code) should only handle mapping that actual REST api and parameter parsing to match the API spec coded in swagger.  After any parameter parsing (again, generated code) it should call directly over to my (non-generated) backend.

My question is, how best to hook these up withOUT hand-editing the generated python/flask code? (Feedback on my design, or details of a formal design pattern that accomplishes this would be great too; I'm new to this space).

Fresh from the generator, I end up with python functions like:

```
def create_task(myTaskDefinition):
    """
    comment as specified in swagger.json
    :param myTaskDefinition: json blah blah blah
    :type myTaskDefinition: dict | bytes
    :rtype: ApiResponse
    """
    if connexion.request.is_json:
        myTaskDefinition = MyTaskTypeFromSwagger.from_dict(connexion.request.get_json())
    return 'do some magic!' # swagger codegen inserts this string :)
```

On the backend I have my actual logic:

```
def create_task_backend(myTaskDefinition):
    # hand-coded, checked into git: do all the things
    return APIResponse(...)
```

What is the right way to get `create_task()` to call `create_task_backend()`?

Of course if I make breaking changes to my swagger spec I will have to hand-update the non-generated code regardless; however there are many reasons I may want to re-generate my API (say, add/refine the `MyTaskTypeFromSwagger` class, or skip checking into git the generated code at all) and if I have to hand-edit the generated API code, then all those edits are blown away with each re-generation.

Of course I could script this with a ~simple grammar in eg. pyparsing; but while this is my first time with this issue, it seems likely it's been widely solved already!

Comment: Note, i did see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252817/swagger-codegen-is-overwriting-my-custom-code-in-generated-files, however it seems that by simply exempting some files from generation I loose stuff like automated method comments, parameter deserialization, etc.   I'd like to be guaranteed the python entrypoint in the (generated) controller is always in sync with the swagger.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following approach worked for me:

- created three directories:

  - `src` - for my code,
  - `src-gen` for the swagger generated code,
  - `codegen` in which I have put a script that generate the server along with a few tricks.
- I copied all the templates (available in the swagger build) to `codegen/templates` and edited the `controller.mustache` to refer to `src/server_impl`, so it can use my own code. The editing uses the template language so it is generic. Still it is not perfect (I would change a few naming conventions) but it does the job. So, first add to `controller.mustache`:

```mustache
from {{packageName}}.server_impl.controllers_impl import {{classname}}_impl
```

then add instead of `return 'do some magic!'` the following:

```mustache
return {{classname}}_impl.{{operationId}}({{#allParams}}{{paramName}}{{^required}}=None{{/required}}{{#hasMore}}, {{/hasMore}}{{/allParams}})
```

- Script:

  - The `src` has a `server_impl` directory.
  - It creates a symobolic link so that `server_impl` can be imported as a python module

```sh
cd ../src-gen/swagger_server/
ln -s ../../src/server_impl/
cd ../../codegen
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate  \
-i /path_to_your_swagger definition.yaml \
-l python-flask \
-o ../src-gen \
-t ./templates
cd ../src-gen/
python3 -m swagger_server
```

Comment: Awesome!
Just missing an opening bracket in "{packageName}}"

Comment: @Dudi Thanks for the solution. For not required parameters, you should not pass `None` in arguments while calling `{{operationId}}` so the second line to be added into `controller.mustache` should be: `return {{classname}}_impl.{{operationId}}({{#allParams}}{{paramName}}{{#hasMore}}, {{/hasMore}}{{/allParams}})`

Comment: `hasMore` has been removed from openapi-generator (see https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/7882), so in order to make this answer work as of today, you need to replace `{{#hasMore}}, {{/hasMore}}` with `{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}`

Answer (score 6):

I was tempted to use `swagger-codegen` before and ran into the same conundrum. Everything is fine until you update the spec. Although you can use custom templates, this just seemed like a lot of overhead and maintenance, when all I want is a design first API.

I ended up using [connexion](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/connexion) instead, which uses the swagger specification to automatically handle routing, marshaling, validation, etc. Connexion is built on flask, so you would not need to worry about switching frameworks or anything, you will just get the benefit of portions of your application being automatically handled from swagger instead of having to maintain auto-generated code.

Comment: I see SwaggerCodegen is using Connexion under the hood; seems like a pretty straightforward use (`x-swagger-router-controller` and `operationId`).  I had assumed it was advantageous to use the SwaggerCodegen; any idea what benefit it adds over 'raw' Connexion?

Comment: Looks trivial to hook up my hand-coded functions directly in the swagger (as swagger-codegen does).  However, I'm not finding a good example showing what connexion provides for generated parameter validation.  any resources you could point me to?  Thanks!

Comment: No worries, it is hidden in the docs:

https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request.html#request-validation

Comment: I've played around with this.  It works as expected, however I give up a lot, namely generation of all the boilerplate controllers and responses.  I've upvoted your comment here as a thanks for the thought and time to respond, but I really fell there should be something better.  Swagger codegen appears popular and robust; does it really have ~zero mindshare?

Answer (score 1):

For now I am working around this by doing the build in these steps

1. run the codegen
2. sed-script the generated code to fix trivial stuff like namespaces
3. hand-edit the files, so that instead of returning `'do some magic'` (thats the string all the generated controller endpoints return) they simply call a corresponding function in my 'backend'
4. use `git format-patch` to make a patch of the preceeding changes, so that when i re-generated code the build can automatically apply the changes.

Thus, i can add new endpoints and I only have to hand-code the calls to my backend ~once.  Instead of using patch files, i could do this directly by writing a py-parsing grammar for the generated code and using the parsed generated code to create the calls to my backend ... that would take longer so I did this all as a quick hack.

This is far from optimal, i'm not going to mark this as accepted as I'm hoping someone will offer a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow I came to.

The idea is to generate the code, then extract `swagger_server` package to the project directory. But separately, keep controllers your are coding in the separate directory or (as I do) in the project root and **merge** them with generated ones after each generations using `git merge-files`. Then you need to **inject** your fresh controllers code into `swagger_server/controllers`, i.e. before starting server.

```
project
+-- swagger_server
|   +-- controllers
|       +-- controller.py <- this is generated
+-- controller.py <- this is you are typing your code in
+-- controller.py.common <- common ancestor, see below
+-- server.py <- your server code, if any
```

So the workflow is the following:

1. Generate code, copy `swagger_server` to your project directory, completely overwrite existing
2. Backup `controller.py` and `controller.py.common` from project root
3. `git merge-file controller.py controller.py.common swagger_server/controllers/controller.py`
4. Make `swagger_server/controllers/controller.py` new common ancestor so copy it to `controller.py.common`, overwrite existing

Feel free to automate all of this with shell script, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Swagger generate server and client stub based on specification, them merge it into the project.
# Use carefully! Commit always before using this script!
# The following structure is assumed:
# .
# +-- my_client
# |   +-- swagger_client
# +-- my_server
# |   +-- swagger_server
# +-- merge.sh <- this script

read -p "Have you commited the project??? " -n 1 -r
if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then echo 'Commit first!'; exit 1; fi

rm -rf swagger-python-client
rm -rf swagger-python-server

java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i swagger.yaml -l python -o swagger-python-client 
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i swagger.yaml -l python-flask -o swagger-python-server

# Client - it's easy, just replace swagger_client package
rm -rf my_client/swagger_client
cp -rf swagger-python-client/swagger_client/ my_client

# Server - replace swagger_server package and merge with controllers
rm -rf my_server/.backup
mkdir -p my_server/.backup
cp -rf my_server/swagger_server my_server/.backup


rm -rf my_server/swagger_server
cp -rf swagger-python-server/swagger_server my_server


cd my_server/swagger_server/controllers/
files=$( ls * )
cd ../../..

for f in $files; do

    # skip __init__.py
    if [ -z "$flag" ]; then flag=1; continue; fi
    echo "======== $f"

    # initialization
    cp -n my_server/swagger_server/controllers/$f my_server/$f.common
    cp -n my_server/swagger_server/controllers/$f my_server/$f


    # real merge
    cp -f my_server/$f my_server/.backup/
    cp -f my_server/$f.common my_server/.backup/
    git merge-file my_server/$f my_server/$f.common my_server/swagger_server/controllers/$f
    cp -f my_server/swagger_server/controllers/$f otmini-repo/$f.common

done

rm -rf swagger-python-client
rm -rf swagger-python-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io) as @MrName suggested.

I first started using this together with codegen.

`openapi-generator generate -i ../myapi.yaml -g python-flask -o .`

This generates a directory with the openapi server.

```
  |- openapi_server\
      |--controllers\
           |--mytag._controller.py\
      |--openapi\
           |--my-api.yaml\
```

If you add tags to your paths in the api spec, then a separate tagname-controller.py is created for each tag. For each operationId a function is generated.

However, once this is set up, connexion can handle updates to the api spec.
If I add a new path to openapi/my-api.yaml, with an operationId=new_func, then I can add new_func() to the existing controller. I don't lose the existing server logic (but I would still back it up before just in case). I haven't tried radical changes to existing paths yet.